# Angular MVVM + PubSub Architectural Issues

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, mediator

Imagine I had an app structured in the following way:

I have a parent controller. It's job is purely to capture events and notify various services of these events. Generally, it's business models broadcasting a change and other business models reacting to this change. This seems to work well apart from I've got two stumbling blocks:

My ViewModels are notified in this way. The UserService will broadcast that the selected user has changed and in the controller, I'll tell the relevant ViewModels of this change. Ideally I'd want my VMs to listen to the model directly, however, my VMs are all used by directives (so my VMs aren't instantiated just yet - hence why my subscribers won't be fired). These directives aren't always on screen, however, I populate their respective VM ready for when the directive is instantiated. Are there any opinions / suggestions about this approach?

My next issue is that imagine my user has many accounts. What id like to do is to be able to compare their accounts side by side in a tab like solution. This is becoming difficult because all my objects are static and hence have knowledge of only one account. I still want to use this pub / sub pattern but I need some sort of way of notifying a particular account (tab) of any changes. Will I need my static business models to contain the state for each account / tab which I am viewing? IE, represent each tab inside some sort of array / object inside each static business model?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Tom

Comment: PubSub == Publisher/Subscriber. New subscribers need a way to "catch-up" to the state of the model as well as react to changes to the model. Think of newly instantiated directives as "new subscribers".

Comment: George. I was thinking of some way of allowing the directives to "catch up". The only way to see is to have the VM directly ask the model for state upon instantiation. Don't know how clean this is though?

Comment: The subscriber furnishes an event handler function to the publisher. If the publisher invokes the event handler immediately with the current state, the subscriber immediately does a "catch up".